# Does the XSP2 web server always uses Mono?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mono, xsp, xsp2

I am not sure if XSP2 is using mono or .NET in my Windows box.
How can I be sure?

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Jweede, +1 for the EVE reference. :D

Comment: Did James Cameron play EVE back in the 80's?

Comment: @Venemo It's a Aliens (1986) quote http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/quotes#qt0424740

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know! (Still, it was a notable sentence in the EVE fanfest. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see xsp2.exe in Windows Task Manager, probably it runs on .NET. For mono hosted applications, the process should be mono.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you are launching it via "xsp2.bat" or "mono xsp2.exe" or the right click menu the Mono installer added, it is using Mono.  If you are launching it via "xsp2.exe" or double clicking it, it is using .Net.

Answer (score 0):

There are several utilites to see the DLLs that a process is ruuning. Perhaps [this one from systernals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will help.